# Programmatic zoom in d3 js timeline chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I implement chart to display some financial data for time period, x-axis contains javascript dates but y-axis numbers. The chart must provide zoom and pan functionality. I set x-axis for max available period, like:

```js
var data =  [
 [{'x':'2017-01-02','y':0},{'x':'2017-02-03','y':5.0},{'x':'2017-03-04','y':10},{'x':'2017-04-05','y':0},{'x':'2017-05-06','y':6},{'x':'2017-06-07','y':11},{'x':'2017-07-08','y':9},{'x':'2017-08-09','y':4},{'x':'2017-09-10','y':11},{'x':'2017-10-11','y':2}],
 [{'x':'2017-01-02','y':1},{'x':'2017-02-03','y':6.0},{'x':'2017-03-04','y':11},{'x':'2017-04-05','y':1},{'x':'2017-05-06','y':7},{'x':'2017-06-07','y':12},{'x':'2017-07-08','y':8},{'x':'2017-08-09','y':3},{'x':'2017-09-10','y':13},{'x':'2017-10-11','y':3}]
];

 var json = JSON.parse('[[{"x":"2017-08-22T20:27:53.181+0200","y":4.0},{"x":"2017-09-01T20:27:53.181+0200","y":9.0},{"x":"2017-09-11T20:27:53.181+0200","y":15.0},{"x":"2017-09-21T20:27:53.181+0200","y":6.0},{"x":"2017-10-01T20:27:53.181+02:00","y":13.0},{"x":"2017-10-11T20:27:53.181","y":10.0},{"x":"2017-10-21T20:27:53.181","y":1.0},{"x":"2017-10-31T20:27:53.181","y":13.0},{"x":"2017-11-10T20:27:53.181","y":2.0},{"x":"2017-11-20T20:27:53.181","y":13.0},{"x":"2017-11-30T20:27:53.181","y":2.0},{"x":"2017-12-10T20:27:53.181","y":14.0},{"x":"2017-12-20T20:27:53.181","y":15.0},{"x":"2017-12-30T20:27:53.181","y":11.0},{"x":"2018-01-09T20:27:53.181","y":5.0},{"x":"2018-01-19T20:27:53.181","y":11.0},{"x":"2018-01-29T20:27:53.181","y":5.0},{"x":"2018-02-08T20:27:53.181","y":2.0},{"x":"2018-02-18T20:27:53.181","y":4.0},{"x":"2018-02-28T20:27:53.181","y":3.0},{"x":"2018-03-10T20:27:53.181","y":2.0},{"x":"2018-03-20T20:27:53.181","y":10.0},{"x":"2018-03-30T20:27:53.181","y":15.0},{"x":"2018-04-09T20:27:53.181","y":3.0},{"x":"2018-04-19T20:27:53.181","y":2.0},{"x":"2018-04-29T20:27:53.181","y":11.0},{"x":"2018-05-09T20:27:53.181","y":7.0},{"x":"2018-05-19T20:27:53.181","y":13.0},{"x":"2018-05-29T20:27:53.181","y":8.0},{"x":"2018-06-08T20:27:53.181","y":1.0},{"x":"2018-06-18T20:27:53.181","y":4.0},{"x":"2018-06-28T20:27:53.181","y":10.0},{"x":"2018-07-08T20:27:53.181","y":13.0},{"x":"2018-07-18T20:27:53.181","y":13.0},{"x":"2018-07-28T20:27:53.181","y":12.0},{"x":"2018-08-07T20:27:53.181","y":13.0},{"x":"2018-08-17T20:27:53.181","y":13.0},{"x":"2018-08-27T20:27:53.181","y":1.0},{"x":"2018-09-06T20:27:53.181","y":8.0},{"x":"2018-09-16T20:27:53.181","y":14.0},{"x":"2018-09-26T20:27:53.181","y":7.0},{"x":"2018-10-06T20:27:53.181","y":9.0},{"x":"2018-10-16T20:27:53.181","y":15.0},{"x":"2018-10-26T20:27:53.181","y":15.0},{"x":"2018-11-05T20:27:53.181","y":11.0},{"x":"2018-11-15T20:27:53.181","y":13.0},{"x":"2018-11-25T20:27:53.181","y":9.0},{"x":"2018-12-05T20:27:53.181","y":5.0},{"x":"2018-12-15T20:27:53.181","y":5.0},{"x":"2018-12-25T20:27:53.181","y":6.0}],[{"x":"2017-08-22T20:27:53.181","y":8.0},{"x":"2017-09-01T20:27:53.181","y":13.0},{"x":"2017-09-11T20:27:53.181","y":15.0},{"x":"2017-09-21T20:27:53.181","y":11.0},{"x":"2017-10-01T20:27:53.181","y":12.0},{"x":"2017-10-11T20:27:53.181","y":10.0},{"x":"2017-10-21T20:27:53.181","y":2.0},{"x":"2017-10-31T20:27:53.181","y":10.0},{"x":"2017-11-10T20:27:53.181","y":12.0},{"x":"2017-11-20T20:27:53.181","y":6.0},{"x":"2017-11-30T20:27:53.181","y":10.0},{"x":"2017-12-10T20:27:53.181","y":2.0},{"x":"2017-12-20T20:27:53.181","y":3.0},{"x":"2017-12-30T20:27:53.181","y":10.0},{"x":"2018-01-09T20:27:53.181","y":12.0},{"x":"2018-01-19T20:27:53.181","y":12.0},{"x":"2018-01-29T20:27:53.181","y":6.0},{"x":"2018-02-08T20:27:53.181","y":2.0},{"x":"2018-02-18T20:27:53.181","y":7.0},{"x":"2018-02-28T20:27:53.181","y":1.0},{"x":"2018-03-10T20:27:53.181","y":10.0},{"x":"2018-03-20T20:27:53.181","y":4.0},{"x":"2018-03-30T20:27:53.181","y":14.0},{"x":"2018-04-09T20:27:53.181","y":15.0},{"x":"2018-04-19T20:27:53.181","y":5.0},{"x":"2018-04-29T20:27:53.181","y":14.0},{"x":"2018-05-09T20:27:53.181","y":4.0},{"x":"2018-05-19T20:27:53.181","y":3.0},{"x":"2018-05-29T20:27:53.181","y":7.0},{"x":"2018-06-08T20:27:53.181","y":1.0},{"x":"2018-06-18T20:27:53.181","y":14.0},{"x":"2018-06-28T20:27:53.181","y":2.0},{"x":"2018-07-08T20:27:53.181","y":14.0},{"x":"2018-07-18T20:27:53.181","y":11.0},{"x":"2018-07-28T20:27:53.181","y":12.0},{"x":"2018-08-07T20:27:53.181","y":3.0},{"x":"2018-08-17T20:27:53.181","y":13.0},{"x":"2018-08-27T20:27:53.181","y":6.0},{"x":"2018-09-06T20:27:53.181","y":3.0},{"x":"2018-09-16T20:27:53.181","y":11.0},{"x":"2018-09-26T20:27:53.181","y":3.0},{"x":"2018-10-06T20:27:53.181","y":15.0},{"x":"2018-10-16T20:27:53.181","y":13.0},{"x":"2018-10-26T20:27:53.181","y":9.0},{"x":"2018-11-05T20:27:53.181","y":2.0},{"x":"2018-11-15T20:27:53.181","y":14.0},{"x":"2018-11-25T20:27:53.181","y":15.0},{"x":"2018-12-05T20:27:53.181","y":4.0},{"x":"2018-12-15T20:27:53.181","y":2.0},{"x":"2018-12-25T20:27:53.181","y":5.0}]]');
 var a = jsonToArray(json);

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;
data.forEach(function(d) {
 d.forEach(function(d2) {
  d2.x = parseDate(d2.x);
 });
});

var colors = [
 'steelblue',
 'green'
]

var pWidth = document.getElementById('chart1').offsetWidth;
var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = pWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 
var x = d3.time.scale()
  .domain([new Date('2016-01-01T00:00:00.000+02:00'), new Date('2018-10-01T00:00:00.000+02:00')])
  .range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([-1, 16])
    .range([height, 0]);
 
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
 .tickSize(-height)
 .tickPadding(10) 
 .tickSubdivide(true) 
    .orient("bottom"); 
 
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
 .tickPadding(10)
 .tickSize(-width)
 .tickSubdivide(true) 
    .orient("left");
 
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(x)
    .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);
 
var svg = d3.select("#chart1").append("svg")
 .call(zoom)
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
 .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
 
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
 
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);
 
svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "y axis")
 .append("text")
 .attr("class", "axis-label")
 .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
 .attr("y", (-margin.left) + 10)
 .attr("x", -height/2)
 .text('Axis Label'); 
 
svg.append("clipPath")
 .attr("id", "clip")
 .append("rect")
 .attr("width", width)
 .attr("height", height);

var line = d3.svg.line() 
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); });  
 
svg.selectAll('.line')
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
 .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
 .attr('stroke', function(d,i){    
  return colors[i%colors.length];
 })
    .attr("d", line);  
 
var points = svg.selectAll('.dots')
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("g")
    .attr("class", "dots")
 .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)"); 
 
function zoomed() {
 svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);  
 svg.selectAll('path.line').attr('d', line);  
 
 var arr = [[]];
 for ( var i = 0; i < 2; i++ ) {
   arr[i] = new Array();
   for ( var j = 0; j < 50; j++ ) {
    arr[i][j] = {'x': addDays(x.domain()[0], 10*j), 'y':Math.floor((Math.random() * 15) + 1)};
   }
 }

    svg.selectAll('.line')
     .data(arr)
     .enter()
     .append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
     .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
     .attr('stroke', function(d,i){
      return colors[i%colors.length];
     })
        .attr("d", line); 
}


 function addDays(startDate,numberOfDays)
 {
  var returnDate = new Date(
        startDate.getFullYear(),
        startDate.getMonth(),
        startDate.getDate()+numberOfDays,
        startDate.getHours(),
        startDate.getMinutes(),
        startDate.getSeconds());
  return returnDate;
 }
 
 function jsonToArray(json) {
  var result = new Array();
  for(var i in json) {
   var arr = new Array();
   for(var j in json[i]) {
    arr.push({'x':new Date(json[i][j].x), 'y':json[i][j].y});
   }
   result.push(arr);
  }
  return result;
 }
}
```

but default time period when chart is loaded must be current date - one month back. And when I draw path for this period, chart displays it on the x-axis with max period. How can I programmatically zoom in to the default period (current date - one month back) so afterwards I can make both zoom in and zoom out?
Or I can set default period (current date - one month back) when chart is loaded but how can then make zoom out scrolling mouse wheel to wider period?

Comment: d3 scale, as the name suggests, scales a domain of values to the target range. You need to provide more code for others to be able to help you.

You can consult [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guidelines to learn more about the code you need to post in your question.

Comment: thanks for a point, full code added